# Form submit button and textfield in same line

Tags: html, css

I want my serchbox textfield and submit button in same line. I have tried but its changing browser to browser. Need assistance.
Heres my css:

```
.search  input[type="text"]{
            width: 70px; height: 25px;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
            font-size: 15;
            margin: 0px -3px 0px 0px;
}
.search  input[type="submit"]{
            background: url(/images/search.png) no-repeat 4 4;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
            font-size: 12;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
            border-radius: 0px;
}
.search input[type="submit"], input[type="text"] {
    line-height:normal !important;
}
```

Heres my html form

```
<form method='get' class='search' action='example.php'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Search' name='search' value=''/>
<input type='submit' value=''/>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML as well. It would be best to create a snippet or link to a jsFiddle so we can see it live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple add `vertical-align: bottom`:

```css
.search input[type="text"] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 15;
  margin: 0px -3px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: bottom;/*add vertical align bottom*/
}
.search input[type="submit"] {
  background: url(/images/search.png) no-repeat 4 4;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 12;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.search input[type="submit"],
input[type="text"] {
  line-height: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<form method='get' class='search' action='example.php'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Search' name='search' value='' />
  <input type='submit' value='' />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome.. Worked.. Thanx..I will accept your ans. soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use display: `inline-block` or floating with: `float: left;` **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w4aospj1/)**

And fix your font sizes, add `px` after them

HTML

```
<form class="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.search  input[type="text"]{
    width: 70px; height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px -3px 0px 0px;
}
.search  input[type="submit"]{
    background: url(/images/search.png) no-repeat 4 4;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.search input[type="submit"], input[type="text"] {
    line-height:normal !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, in these type of layout, such a form and text elements, is always better to sue the inline-block that is fully sopported, instead of floating the elements, due to the need to assigning the width and clearing the float for the parent(s).

Comment: You are right, this is why I  used the `inline-block`, but that could be a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div around the input box and the search button to wrap the two elements. Give this div a width, say 200px. Then, give the input box a left float and width of 50% and the same to the submit button. Voila, they'll sit side by side as long as there's 200px of space for the wrapper to sit in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use inline-block:

```
.search input[type="text"], input[type="text"] {display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this.

```
your-element {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px; /* You need a given width */
}
```

**Note:** You need a given width so the individual elements don't take up the full width.